# UE4 set Actor pointer to null without destroying it in the world

Tags: c++, pointers, unreal-engine4, spawn, nullptr

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to reset the pointer of an Actor and simultaneously not make it disappear from the world.
Example:
 1. `auto Item = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<...>(...);`
 2. ...
 3. `Item = nullptr;`- resetting just the pointer
 4. Actor is still in the world
I believe that duplicating this actor would work, but it mustn't be the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be working with the assumption that clearing a pointer will *automatically* destroy the Actor.  Have you verified that is actually the case?

[Looking at the docs](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UWorld/SpawnActor/index.html), `SpawnActor` just returns a regular 'dumb' pointer.  In C++, resetting a plain pointer to `null` *does not destroy* the object it references; some explicit action is probably needed, to destroy it. The UE4 article on [Actor Lifecycle](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Actors/ActorLifecycle) seems to support this as well.

This could probably take the form of resetting a [*smart pointer*](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/SmartPointerLibrary) (`TSharedPtr`), or calling `Destroy` on the actor itself.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I hadn't checked it in the World Outliner before and now as I see, the actor is still in the world, but teleports to a strange position and does some strange stuff. Thanks